# Are there any Demigods who became gods of their own power?

Tags: comparative, demi-gods

The only "demigod" I know who would apply would be Dionysus in Greek mythology who had to prove his divinity but didn't need other gods to raise him up to godhood. Are there any others like him in any mythology?

Comment: Hi and welcome to M&F SE, please take some time to take our [tour](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/tour). Interesting question, but it may just need some details on how you want to choose the answer between the many that may arise.

Answer (score 5):

Heracles is one of the most famous characters in Greek Mythology who transcended from being a demigod to a god. Throughout his life, Heracles faced constant trials, many of them concocted by Hera due to her hatred at Zeus' interactions with Heracles' mother (a mortal woman).

The story of Heracles' death begins with a centaur who attempted to kidnap Heracles' wife, Deianira, and was slain by her husband's wrath. In the centaur's dying breath, he gave Deianira the blood-stained tunic which he wore and told her that it was, essentially, a love potion for Heracles.

Years passed, and Deianira heard rumors that Heracles may have had a rival lover. Not knowing any better, Deianira gave her husband the tunic, thinking it would rekindle his love for her. Instead, the tunic (soaked in the centaur's blood which had been tainted by the Hydra's poison from Heracles' arrows) caused the skin to consume away on Heracles' body. He writhed in agony, and as a last resort to end the pain, he ordered a pyre be ignited to be burned upon.

As he died, he left his mortal body behind, and his immortal spirit drifted to Mount Olympus where he became fully divine. It may not have necessarily been his power that caused his transcendence, but it could very well have been the case. He wasn't raised by other gods, instead, he fought against them to earn his place among the Olympians *because of* of his strength and willpower.

See Also: [The Death of Heracles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heracles#Death)

Comment: Hi, nice answer, could you space it up a bit and add some link to sustain the informations you gave?

Comment: Sure! No problem!

Comment: Nice answer.  You may find this post interesting: [What is the meaning of Hercules' self-immolation?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/what-is-the-meaning-of-hercules-self-immolation).  I'd say it was *definitely* Heracles' power than led to his immortality--[he'd already defeated Death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcestis) and so could not die!  Once they separated the mortal part from the divine, his body could finally expire.

Comment: *PS- feel free to integrate the note on the Alcestis into your answer!  I replaced your reference link with the wiki, which is more accurate and non-commercial.  All of the basic info is correct and consistent.*